# Error while Looping Through conditions for Outlook VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

My original Question is here

[Looping through Arrays with VBA, to Move outlook emails from one folder to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57591174/looping-through-arrays-with-vba-to-move-outlook-emails-from-one-folder-to-anoth/57595688#57595688)

but i figured that the code i created was too complex. I simplified it as below, now it only has one array.

Looping through Arrays with VBA, to Move outlook emails from one folder to another? - original question

```
Sub MovingEmails_Invoices()

  'Declare your Variables
    Dim NS As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim rootfol As Outlook.Folder
    Dim Fol As Outlook.Folder
    Dim subfolder As Outlook.Folder


    'Set Outlook Inbox Reference
    Set OP = New Outlook.Application
    Set NS = OP.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set rootfol = NS.Folders(7)

    ' loop through subfolder and its folder
    Set Fol = rootfol.Folders("Austria")
    Set subfolder = rootfol.Folders("Austria").Folders("MOVE")

'The list for invoice numbers and folders is dynamic
'Each subject being searched is different

Dim Listmails() As Variant
Dim Rowcount As Long
Dim Mailsubject As Variant
Dim MS As String
Dim myrestrictitem As Outlook.items
Dim myItem As Outlook.Mailitem

'Establish the array based on the mailbox extract
  Sheets("files").Activate
  Listmails = Range("A2").CurrentRegion

'Ititerate through the array which is dynamic (One-dimensional)
For Rowcount = LBound(Listmails) To UBound(Listmails)

   '3rd row for email subject 'used DASL Filter
    Mailsubject = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Listmails, Rowcount, 3)
    MS = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:mailheader:subject"" LIKE \'%" & Mailsubject &"%\'"

    'Find the email based on the array for email subject
    Set myitems = Fol.items
    Set myrestrictitem = myitems.Restrict(MS)

    For i = myrestrictitem.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set item = myrestrictitem.item(i)
    myrestrictitem(i).Move subfolder

Next Rowcount

End Sub
```

The error is caused by; and the error is 'it is an invalid Next control Variable reference'

```
Next Rowcount
```

***EDIT***

I re-edited my code according recommendations below, thank you however i still have an error for the syntax 'Rowcount'

The error message, is that 'it is an invalid Next control Variable reference'

```
The list for invoice numbers and folders is dynamic
'Each subject being searched is different

Dim Listmails() As Variant
Dim Rowcount As Long
Dim Mailsubject As Variant
Dim MS As String
Dim myrestrictitem As Outlook.items
Dim myItem As Outlook.Mailitem

'Establish the array based on the mailbox extract
  Sheets("files").Activate
  Listmails = Range("A2").CurrentRegion

'Ititerate through the array which is dynamic (One-dimensional)
For Rowcount = LBound(Listmails) To UBound(Listmails)

   '3rd row for email subject 'used DASL Filter
    Mailsubject = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Listmails, Rowcount, 3)
    MS = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:mailheader:subject"" LIKE \'%" & Mailsubject & "%\'"

    'Find the email based on the array for email subject
    Set myitems = Fol.items
    Set myrestrictitem = myitems.Restrict(MS)

    For i = myrestrictitem.Count To 1 Step -1
    myrestrictitem(i).Move subfolder

    Next i
Next Rowcount

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you could ask about _just_ the restrict method as a clarifying comment on @DmitryStreblechenko 's answer to your original question. As for the rest of the question, I'm having a hard time seeing how it's different from the first one. Are you having the same issue as you did with the prior code?

Comment: You do not have a `Next i` for `For i = myrestrictitem.Count To 1 Step -1`

Comment: Perfect, thank you! could i ask if what i did with with the code `MS = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:mailheader:subject"" LIKE \'%" & Mailsubject &"%\'" ` correct?  is placing 'Mailsubject' is ok?

Comment: Hi Mistella, i wanted the folder that the email move to be dynamic but when i assigned the array foldername -  `FolderName = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Listmails, Rowcount,8)` to  `Set subfolder = rootfol.Folders(FolderName) ` i got an error.. still

Comment: pedro_91 I haven't used a restrict method before, and don't currently understand it. Since @DmitryStreblechenko suggested it, I assume they understand it enough to verify if you are using it correctly; which is why I recommended commenting directly on one of their answers to your question(s). Also, when you are trying to get help for an error, you really need to include the error message, and maybe the error number, along with the line which is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your "for" loop is wrong:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = myrestrictitem.Count To 1 Step -1
  Set item = myrestrictitem.item(i)
  myrestrictitem(i).Move subfolder
next
```

Comment: Oh alright, i edited now :) thank you. I still have an error for `Next Rowcount` :(

Comment: Hi Dmitry, i rewrote the code in the question space once again, However i still hv the Rowcount syntax error. Thanks for your help

Comment: What is the exact error? Try to declare Rowcount as Integer. You also need to declare the i variable.